# googlemaps api with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm using googlemaps API and I'd like to be able to search for stores in the db on the map. I'm also using the geokit-rails gem. However, I'm getting the following error on form_for(@song):

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

**queries_controller:**

```
class QueriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @store = Store.find(:all)
  end
end
```

**queries#index:**

```
 = form_for(@store) do |f|                                                
    .field                                                                  
  %f.label>                                                         
  \%> br                                                              
  \#(f.check_box :active)                                                    
  %br/
```

**schema.rb:**

```
     ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 0) do

      create_table "queries", :options => 'ENGINE=MyISAM', force: true do |t|
        t.string   "uuid",           limit: 250
        t.float    "lat",                        null: false
        t.float    "lng",                        null: false
        t.float    "execution_time",             null: false
        t.integer  "gps_accuracy",               null: false
        t.integer  "mode",           limit: 1,   null: false
        t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
      end

      create_table "stores", :options => 'ENGINE=MyISAM', force: true do |t|
        t.string  "name",          limit: 250, default: "",   null: false
        t.string  "subname",       limit: 250, default: "",   null: false
        t.string  "phone",         limit: 250, default: "",   null: false
        t.string  "address",       limit: 250, default: "",   null: false
        t.string  "city",          limit: 100, default: "",   null: false
        t.string  "province",      limit: 50,  default: "",   null: false
        t.string  "postalCode",    limit: 25,  default: "",   null: false
        t.float   "lat",                                      null: false
        t.float   "lng",                                      null: false
      t.integer  "mode",           limit: 1,   null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
  end



     create_table "stores", :options => 'ENGINE=MyISAM', force: true do |t|
        t.string  "name",          limit: 250, default: "",   null: false
        t.string  "subname",       limit: 250, default: "",   null: false
        t.string  "phone",         limit: 250, default: "",   null: false
        t.string  "address",       limit: 250, default: "",   null: false
        t.string  "city",          limit: 100, default: "",   null: false
        t.string  "province",      limit: 50,  default: "",   null: false
        t.string  "postalCode",    limit: 25,  default: "",   null: false
        t.float   "lat",                                      null: false
        t.float   "lng",                                      null: false
        t.integer "store_type",    limit: 1
        t.boolean "active",                    default: true, null: false
      end

    end
```

**store.rb**

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base                                                                                                                              

end
```

Comment: It would appear that `@store` (which should probably be `@stores`) is empty. Do you have any values in your database? Also, you can just use `Store.all`

Comment: Ya I have a ton of seed data, that's why I'm a little stumped here

Comment: What does `Store.all` return?

Comment: it returns : undefined method `model_name' for ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Store:Class

Comment: And your `Store.find(:all)`?

Comment: undefined method `store_store_store_store_store_store_store_store_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fa15e86dc40>:0x007fa15ec20220>

Comment: Ok. What does your `Store` model look like?

Comment: Can you put it in the question?

Comment: What does `<%= @store.inspect %>` show you?

Comment: That outputs in the view: 'store
%> br #(f.check_box :active) '

Comment: screenmutt, it's a tough cookie - do you use teamviewer? i'll give u quick control of the app n see if u can spot anything

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41047/discussion-between-sonny-black-and-screenmutt)